# Sum Datagrid Column

Tags: c#, wpf

I am looking to sum a column on a simplified datagrid when I add new rows, but I have no idea how to do this.  Can someone tell me how I would go about this?

Thanks for your help as always.

```
   XAML
   <Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="ResultsDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="134" Width="835" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" />
    <Button x:Name="AddResult" Content="Add Row" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="847,179,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="AddResult_Click"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="noofrows" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="813,180,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="29"/>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="No. of Rows" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="741,177,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>

   c#
   public class AddResultRow
{
    public string InspectionFee { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<AddResultRow> _items = new ObservableCollection<AddResultRow>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ResultsDataGrid.ItemsSource = _items;
    }

    private AddResultRow addnewrow()
    {
        return new AddResultRow()
        {
            InspectionFee = ""
        };
    }

    public void AddResult_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _items.Add(addnewrow());
        int rowCount = ResultsDataGrid.Items.Count;
        noofrows.Text = rowCount.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
using System.Linq;
public int SumOfFees() {
   return items_.ToList().Where(x => Int32.TryParse(x.InspectionFee, out var result)).Sum(x => Int32.Parse(x.InspectionFee));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MSDN about Grouping Sorting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.100).aspx) They provide a **complete working example**, that includes Totals rows. In the example they provide itemCount (not sum), but the `completeConverter` they provide is a row by row calculation that you can use to create a sum as well as other types of 'per row' evaluations. [image: grouping, sorting, totals and filters]

Comment: It may seem like an overkill, but it can give you so much, and be useful in so many applications, that it's worth the effort to get it working. You will not regret the effort.

Comment: Thanks Guy, I think this could be useful going forward as the above example I have posted was just to sum a column, but I have more complicated datagrids that would require this sort of detail.  I will take a look.